# Comparing two tables in two different, but structurally identical databases is not returning expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, subquery

I am not sure how to approach this problem.

I am trying to find all the professors from the year 2020 database that are NOT in year 2019 database.

The two databases are structurally identical, it's just that some of the data is different.

If I run this query:

```
SELECT  * FROM year_2020.dbo.classList 
WHERE professorID NOT IN(SELECT professorID FROM year_2019.dbo.classList)
```

I get 0 results

Which I know is not right.

Because I can take a professorID that is 2020:

```
SELECT * FROM year_2020.dbo.classList WHERE classID = 'bb101'
```

and I see the professorID of 'rts103' like this:

```
classID    dateStart     DeptId     professorID
bb101      2/1/2020      soc3       rts103
```

Then I can do the same thing for 2019:

```
SELECT * FROM year_2019.dbo.classList WHERE classID = 'bb101'
```

And I see he's NOT in this database:

```
classID    dateStart     DeptId     professorID
bb101      2/1/2019      soc3       NULL
```

So I am not sure what's going on.

Is there a better way to formulate this query?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it impossible that 2020 professor `'rts103'` taught a _different_ class in 2019? Your query checked for existence of the professor, not that they were teaching the same class in each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend `not exists`. Also, your question makes it look like you want to correlated rows on `professorID` *and* `classID`, so:

```
SELECT c20.* 
FROM year_2020.dbo.classList c20
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM year_2019.dbo.classList c19
    WHERE c19.professorID = c20.professorID AND c19.classID = c20.classID
)
```

Comment: wow!  Ok I see results now! So is this query showing me all the rows in `year_2020.dbo.classList` where the professorID  in `year_2019.dbo.classList` is missing or NULL?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As there are some NULL values for ProfessorID, NOT IN will not work.

NOT IN is evaluated as given below:

```
WHERE SomeValue NOT IN (3,NULL)
```

is converted to

```
WHERE SomeValue != 3 AND SomeValue != NULL
```

[Read more about NOT IN Vs NOT EXISTS](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/)

It is preferred to use NOT EXISTS Clause, as suggested by [@GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb)

There is also one more approach, as they are identical tables. You can use EXCEPT clause.

```sql
;WITH CTE_2020NewProfessors AS
(
SELECT  ProfessorID FROM year_2020.dbo.classList 
EXCEPT
SELECT professorID FROM year_2019.dbo.classList
)
SELECT * FROM year_2020.dbo.classList 
WHERE ProfessorID in (SELECT professorID from CTE_2020NewProfessors)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also compare all rows - like this - even if it's expensive ...

```
WITH
classlist2020(classid,datestart,deptid,professorid) AS (
          SELECT 'bb101','2020-02-01','soc3','rts103'
)
,
classlist2019(classid,datestart,deptid,professorid) AS (
          SELECT 'bb101','2020-02-01','soc3',NULL
)
SELECT * FROM classlist2020
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM classlist2019
-- out  classid | datestart  | deptid | professorid 
-- out ---------+------------+--------+-------------
-- out  bb101   | 2020-02-01 | soc3   | rts103
```